# How to invoke a rest service via a bookmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, rest, bookmarklet

I have a rest service which accepts a URL parameter: `myService/add?pageUrl=www.google.com`

I'm trying to add this as a bookmark so whenever the user clicks the bookmark the current page URL is sent to my rest service.

Here is the javascript code I am using but the service is not being invoked

```
javascript:function savePage() {
    window.open('myService/add?pageUrl=' + document.URL) 
    alert('Page saved');
}
savePage();
```

I receive the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

How can the above javascript be amended to so that when I add the code to a bookmark my service is invoked and the current URL the user is visiting is sent to the service?

Comment: Have you got a `;` between `window.open(...)` and `alert`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create bookmarklets like this:

```
javascript:(function(){/* your code here */})();
```

So, in your case:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('myService/add?pageUrl='+document.URL)})();
```

After the `javascript:` section, you have a self-executing (anonymous) function:

```
(function(){})()
```

And code in there will be evaluated.
Also, make sure you're not missing any semicolons (`;`). Those will break your code in bookmarklets.

Comment: I like your answer better :-)

Comment: Yes but I think that the issue is rather coming from a missing semi-colon than using a self-executing function :)

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie: Technically, that's correct, yes. I'm more focusing on the fact that in bookmarklets, you generally want self-executing functions, instead of having to call them at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Missing a semicolon.

```
javascript:function savePage(){ window.open('myService/add?pageUrl='+document.URL
);
alert('Page saved');
} savePage();
```